# Use repeating iterator in python to insert item into list

Tags: python, iterator, repeat

The solution below is working but I wanted to know if the code can be improved or if there is a more effective method of achieving the same results. I need to insert a "prefix" in the beginning of my list and I am using an iterator to do so. The prefix is 'a' for line 1, 'b' for line 2 and 'c' for line 3 and then restart at 'a' for line 4 etc..

test file:

```
this,is,line,one
this,is,line,two
this,is,line,three
this,is,line,four
this,is,line,five
this,is,line,six
this,is,line,seven
this,is,line,eight
this,is,line,nine
```

Code:

```
l = ['a','b','c']
it = iter(l)

with open('C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\test_my_it.csv', 'rU') as c:
    rows = csv.reader(c)
    for row in rows:
        try:
            i = it.next()
            newrow = [i] + row
        except StopIteration:
            it = iter(l)
            i = it.next()
            newrow = [i] + row
        print(newrow)
```

Results are:

```
['a', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'one']
['b', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'two']
['c', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'three']
['a', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'four']
['b', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'five']
['c', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'six']
['a', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'seven']
['b', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'eight']
['c', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'nine']
```

Comment: *"The solution below is working but I wanted to know if the code can be improved or if there is a more effective method of achieving the same results."* - This is a good sign that you might be better off posting on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour), read through that how to ask page and see if it might be relevant there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just cycle the list `l` using [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), zipping the cycle object and your rows  with [itertools.izip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip):

```
from itertools import cycle, izip

l = ['a','b','c']
it = iter(l)
import csv
with open('in.csv', 'rU') as c:
    rows = csv.reader(c)
    for a, row in izip(cycle(l), rows):
        print([a]+ row)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'one']
['b', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'two']
['c', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'three']
['a', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'four']
['b', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'five']
['c', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'six']
['a', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'seven']
['b', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'eight']
['c', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'nine']
```

Answer (score 6):

This could be much simpler with [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), which will handle endlessly repeating `l` for you:

```
from itertools import cycle, izip

l = ['a','b','c']

with open('C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\test_my_it.csv', 'rU') as c:
    rows = csv.reader(c)
    for prefix, row in izip(cycle(l), rows):
        newrow = [prefix] + row
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the people have spoken - they prefer puppies to booze!

Comment: It was non-alcoholic, unlike the very alcoholic wine I had last night!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham clearly you've convinced the OP, at least ;o)